# Sci-fi short story about very low educated farmers with paranormal skills

Tags: story-identification

I have read it sometime in the late 80s, but the story itself might have written any time before.

Story is from the point of view of a farmer family, maybe (not sure) in the middle states of the USA. He explains, how things are going there. The main line is, as he is thinking about the world, is very, very low educated. For example, he thinks that the aircrafts, really, do not fly. He, with his family, have strong "supernormal" abilities, like telekinetics and similar. The mainline of the story is that the farmer remembers events as they have interacted with their conflicts with the external world.

Important thing in these interactions, that the family - living semi-isolated, with little external interaction and very low education - does not understand, why external people are surprised on their powers. For them, their powers are normal, and these "visitors" are always babbling. And they dislike this babbling, so they expel or somehow stop these visitors. For example, by *"conserving them in a canned jug"* (sorry that was a back-translation, probably not that is the original text).

The length of the story was about 3 printed pages in a commonly sized scifi book at the time (roughly half-way between a4 and a5).

Unfortunately, now I can not remember any other about the story what I have read many decades ago in another language :-) Secondary signatures show me, it was probably from the U.S. "sci-fi boom" of the 50es, but also sci-fi with non-us origin has some chance.

Comment: [This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145873/40s-50s-short-story-about-a-mutant-family-with-psi-powers) has already asked it, and also [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/42620/56109). It is funny to see as we slowly collect us, from all parts of the world in space and time, for this story. Yes, it is the "Exit The Professor".

Comment: Thanks - I'm going to recommend closing as a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably [*Exit the Professor*](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41423) from 1947 by Henry Kuttner and C. L. Moore, one of several stories about the rural Hogben family each of whom has special powers. This [description](https://sfshortstories.com/?p=4335) is quite detailed, and talks specifically about the container that the family puts a meddling professor in:

> The story ends with Uncle Les rescuing Galbraith from the mob. In
> return he agrees to leave the family alone—but Grandpa reads his mind
> and sees he is lying, so Paw puts Galbraith in a small bottle which he
> never leaves.

It's available at the Internet archive [here](https://archive.org/details/HenryKuttnerC.L.MooreNoBoundariesBallantine1221955/page/n113/mode/2up), which gives me the chance to quote the ending exactly:

> When the mob got here, with Sheriff Abernathy in the lead, we played
> dumb. We let ’em search the house. Little Sam and Grandpaw turned
> invisible for a bit, so nobody noticed them. And naturally the crowd
> couldn’t find hide nor hair of Galbraith. We’d hid him good, like we
> promised.
>
> That was a few years ago. The Perfesser’s thriving. He ain’t studying
> us, though. Sometimes we take out the bottle we keep him in and study
> him.
>
> Dang small bottle, too!

Here's an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hogben_Chronicles) about all  the stories in the series.

Comment: Right! And I am at least the third on this site, coming for this story! :-) Thank you!

Comment: All the stories are available to read or download on fadedpage.com